# I need to create a responsive timetable view in springboot

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new to Spring boot and i'm currently working on a project. I need to create a responsive timetable view(for a particular student group ex: CS year1), when user select a cell he should be redirected to a page where he should be able to add or edit the subject for that particular cell. Can someone please tell me how to do this? thanks.

I have created studentgroup,subject and they are working properly

Student group controller

```
@Controller
public class StudentGroupController {
    @Autowired
    private StudentGroupDAO studentGroupDAO;

    @Autowired
    private CourseDAO courseDAO;


    @RequestMapping("/studentGroup")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model){
        List<StudentGroup> studentGroupDetails= studentGroupDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("studentGroupDetails",studentGroupDetails);
        return "studentGroup";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/studentGroup/new")
    public String addStudentGroup(Model model){
        StudentGroup studentGroup =new StudentGroup();
        model.addAttribute("studentGroup",studentGroup);

        List<Course> courseDetail = courseDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("courses", courseDetail);

        return "addStudentGroup";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/studentGroup/save",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveStudentGroup(@ModelAttribute("studentGroup") StudentGroup studentGroup){
        studentGroupDAO.save(studentGroup);
        return  "redirect:/studentGroup";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/studentGroup/edit/{id}")
    public ModelAndView updateStudentGroup(@PathVariable(name="id")Long id){
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView(("updateStudentGroup"));

        StudentGroup studentGroup = studentGroupDAO.findById(id);
        mav.addObject("studentGroup",studentGroup);

        List<Course> courseDetail = courseDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("courses", courseDetail);

        return  mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/studentGroup/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable(name="id") Long id){
        studentGroupDAO.delete(id);
        return  "redirect:/studentGroup";
    }
}
```

Subject Controller

```
@Controller
public class SubjectController {
    @Autowired
    private SubjectDAO subjectDAO;

    @Autowired
    private CourseDAO courseDAO;

    @Autowired
    private LectureHallDAO lectureHallDAO;


    @RequestMapping("/subject")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model){
        List<Subject> subjectDetails= subjectDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("subjectDetails",subjectDetails);
        return "subject";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/subject/new")
    public String addSubject(Model model){
        Subject subject =new Subject();
        model.addAttribute("subject",subject);

            List<Course> courseDetail = courseDAO.findAll();
            model.addAttribute("courses", courseDetail);


            List<LectureHall> lectureHallDetail = lectureHallDAO.findAll();
            model.addAttribute("lectureHalls",lectureHallDetail);

        return "addSubject";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/subject/save",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveSubject(@ModelAttribute("subject") Subject subject){
        subjectDAO.save(subject);
        return  "redirect:/subject";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/subject/edit/{id}")
    public ModelAndView updateSubjcet(@PathVariable(name="id")Long id){
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView(("updateSubject"));

        Subject subject=subjectDAO.findById(id);
        mav.addObject("subject",subject);

        List<Course> courseDetail = courseDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("courses", courseDetail);
        List<LectureHall> lectureHallDetail = lectureHallDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("lectureHalls",lectureHallDetail);



        return  mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/subject/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable(name="id") Long id){
        subjectDAO.delete(id);
        return  "redirect:/subject";
    }
}
```

Time Table Controller

```
@Controller
public class TimeTableController {
    @Autowired
    private TimeTableDAO timeTableDAO;

    @Autowired
    private SubjectDAO subjectDAO;

    @Autowired
    private StudentGroupDAO studentGroupDAO;


    @RequestMapping("/timeTable")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model){
        List<TimeTable> timeTableDetails= timeTableDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("timeTableDetails",timeTableDetails);
        return "timeTable";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/timeTable/new")
    public String addTimeTable(Model model){
        TimeTable timeTable =new TimeTable();
        model.addAttribute("timeTable",timeTable);

        List<Subject> subjectDetail = subjectDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("subjects", subjectDetail);


        List<StudentGroup> studentGroupDetail = studentGroupDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("studentGroups",studentGroupDetail);

        return "addStudentGroup";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/timeTable/save",method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveTimeTable(@ModelAttribute("timeTable") TimeTable timeTable){
        timeTableDAO.save(timeTable);
        return  "redirect:/timeTable";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/timeTable/edit/{id}")
    public ModelAndView updateTimeTable(@PathVariable(name="id")Long id){
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView(("updateTimeTable"));

        TimeTable timeTable = timeTableDAO.findById(id);
        mav.addObject("timeTable",timeTable);

        List<Subject> subjectDetail = subjectDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("subjects", subjectDetail);
        List<StudentGroup> studentGroupDetail = studentGroupDAO.findAll();
        mav.addObject("studentGroups",studentGroupDetail);

        return  mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/timeTable/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable(name="id") Long id){
        timeTableDAO.delete(id);
        return  "redirect:/timeTable";
    }
}
```

Time Table view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/timetable.css" th:href="@{/css/view.css}">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Time Table</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Time Table</h1>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:30px">
    <br><br>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr><td> 8.00 - 9.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td> 9.00 - 10.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <td>10.00 - 11.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>11.00 - 12.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <td>12.00 - 1.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <td>1.00 - 2.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td> 2.00 - 3.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td> 3.00 - 4.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td> 4.00 - 5.00</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the exact problem that you are facing?Just redirect it to a new page on click of cell

Comment: tbh the whole process. need to select the subject from a dropdown when a cell is selected and then save it in the database